# Why is strict mode not enforced?

Tags: mysql

Here's a snippet from a mysql shell:

```
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                                  |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.27-30                                              |
| protocol_version        | 10                                                     |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                                        |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2                                  |
| version                 | 5.7.27-30                                              |
| version_comment         | Percona Server (GPL), Release '30', Revision '8916819' |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                                 |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu                                       |
| version_suffix          |                                                        |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%strict%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@sql_mode        |
+-------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database stricttest;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use stricttest;
Database changed
mysql> create table foo(bar timestamp not null default current_timestamp);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into foo(bar) values(null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

### The question

I am under the impression that `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` should prevent the insert from succeeding, since `timestamp` is a `NOT NULL` column, but it works just fine.  What can I do to make statements like this fail?

### The context

I recently had a bunch of tests that used to pass start failing due to null inserts on timestamp columns.  I don't know what environmental factor was different, but tribal knowledge around the office says that `sql_mode` has something to with it.  I want to make these tests fail reliably so that the people who wrote them investigate and respond appropriately.

Currently, /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=0
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/general.log

secure_file_priv=""
datadir=/var/lib/mysql

sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
default_time_zone='+00:00'
ssl=0
query_cache_type=0
max_connections=511
group_concat_max_len=65536
max_allowed_packet=500M
max_allowed_packet=256000000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
innodb_log_file_size=1000M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_strict_mode=ON
```

Comment: `default-storage-engine`? Maybe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_strict_mode

Comment: Good idea @LukaszSzozda, but I don't think so.  I enabled `innodb_strict_mode` and see the same behavior (also edited the question to show this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would error if the column didn't have a default value, or if the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` configuration value was set to ON. `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` controls a timestamp-specific variant of strictness, and defaults to OFF. Although the docs aren't absolutely clear on it, it appears that when it is OFF, a `NULL` inserted into a timestamp column with a default will use the default, without triggering any error.

Comment: Setting `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=ON` in mysqld.cnf did the trick.

Comment: Here is a test case on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fwL1rV9m1WAbTdFBTLANxL/0)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the RANGE of TIMESTAMP,

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

you have built in application failure when a date greater than 2038-01-19 date storage is required.

19 years will be gone before you know it.